# Window function behaves differently in Subquery/CTE?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I thought the following three SQL statements are semantically the same. The database engine will expand the second and third query to the first one internally.

```
select .... 
from T 
where Id = 1

select * 
from 
    (select .... from T) t 
where Id = 1

select * 
from 
    (select .... from T where Id = 1) t
```

However, I found the window function behaves differently. I have the following code.

```
-- Prepare test data
with t1 as 
( 
    select *
    from (values ( 2, null), ( 3, 10), ( 5, -1), ( 7, null), ( 11, null), ( 13, -12), ( 17, null), ( 19, null), ( 23, 1759) ) v ( id, col1 )
)
select * 
into #t 
from t1

alter table #t add primary key (id)
go
```

The following query returns all the rows.

```
select  
     id, col1,
     cast(substring(max(cast(id as binary(4)) + cast(col1 as binary(4))) 
                       over (order by id
                             rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding), 5, 4) as int) as lastval
from    
    #t

id  col1    lastval
-------------------
2   NULL    NULL
3   10      NULL
5   -1      10
7   NULL    -1
11  NULL    -1
13  -12     -1
17  NULL    -12
19  NULL    -12
23  1759    -12
```

Without CTE/subquery: then I added a condition just return the row which `Id = 19`.

```
select  
    id, col1,
    cast(substring(max(cast(id as binary(4)) + cast(col1 as binary(4))) over (order by id rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding), 5, 4) as int) as lastval
from    
    #t
where
    id = 19;
```

However, `lastval` returns `null`?

With CTE/subquery: now the condition is applied to the CTE:

```
with t as 
( 
    select   
        id, col1,
        cast(substring(max(cast(id as binary(4)) + cast(col1 as binary(4))) over (order by id rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding ), 5, 4) as int) as lastval
    from     
        #t)
select *
from t
where id = 19;

-- Subquery
select  
    *
from
    (select   
         id, col1,
         cast(substring(max(cast(id as binary(4)) + cast(col1 as binary(4))) over (order by id rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding), 5, 4) as int) as lastval
     from     
         #t) t
where   
    id = 19;
```

Now `lastval` returns `-12` as expected?

Answer (score 2):

The [logic order of operations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-transact-sql) of the SELECT statement is import to understand the results of your first example.  From the Microsoft documentation, the order is, from top to bottom:

> 1. FROM
> 2. ON
> 3. JOIN
> 4. WHERE
> 5. GROUP BY
> 6. WITH CUBE or WITH ROLLUP
> 7. HAVING
> 8. SELECT
> 9. DISTINCT
> 10. ORDER BY
> 11. TOP

Note that the `WHERE` clause processing happens logically before the `SELECT` clause.

The query without the CTE is being filtered `where id = 19`.  The order of operations causes the `where` to process before the window function in the `select` clause.  There is only 1 row with an `id` of 19.  Therefore, the `where` limits the rows to id = 19 before the window function can process the `rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding`.  Since there are no rows for the window function, the `lastval` is `null`.

Compare this to the CTE.  The outer query's filter has not yet been applied, so the CTE operates an all of the data.  The `rows between unbounded preceding` finds the prior rows.  The outer part of the query applies the filter to the intermediate results returns just the row 19 which already has the correct `lastval`.

You can think of the CTE as creating a temporary #Table with the CTE data in it.  All of the data is logically processed into a separate table before returning data to the outer query.  The CTE in your example creates a temporary work table with all of the rows that includes the `lastval` from the prior rows.  Then, the filter in the outer query gets applied and limits the results to `id` 19.

(In reality, the CTE can shortcut and skip generating data, if it can do so to improve performance without affecting the results.  Itzik Ben-Gan has a [great example](http://sqlmag.com/sql-server/virtual-auxiliary-table-numbers) of a CTE that skips processing when it has returned enough data to satisfy the query.)

Consider what happens if you put the filter in the CTE.  This should behave exactly like the first example query that you provided.  There is only 1 row with an id = 19, so the window function does not find any preceding rows:

```
with t as ( select id, col1,
            cast(substring(max(cast(id as binary(4)) + cast(col1 as binary(4))) over ( order by id
               rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding ), 5, 4) as int) as lastval
               from #t
               where id = 19 -- moved filter inside CTE
             )
    select  *
    from t
```

Comment: So for the first two cases in the top of my question, we cannot assume they are semantically the same because of window function. Are the window functions the only ones causing the difference?

Comment: The placement of the filter is what is causing the difference.  If the filter is *inside* the CTE, the window function in the CTE is limited to that row.  If the filter is *outside* the CTE, then the CTE's window function processes all of the rows, and the outer query returns just the filtered row.

Answer (score 0):

Window functions operate on your result set, so when you added `where id = 19` your result set only had 1 row. Since your window function specifies `rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding` there was no preceding row, and resulted in `null`.

By using the subquery/cte you are allowing the window function to operate over the unfiltered result set (where the preceding rows exist), then retrieving only those rows from that result set `where id = 19`.

Comment: So for the first two cases in the top of my question, we cannot assume they are semantically the same because of window function. Are the window functions the only ones causing the difference?

Answer (score 0):

The querys you are comparing are not equivalent.

```
select  id ,
        (... ) as lastval
from    #t
where   id = 19;
```

will take only 1 row, so 'lastval' will take NULL from col1 as for the windowed function does not find preceding row.